# How to stop all notifications and alarms if app is killed by swiping?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-notifications, android-alarms

I want to cancel all of my notifications and alarms set in background as app is killed by swiping. This action will not trigger `onDestroy()` inside my root `Activity`.

I made a background service to call `NotificationManager` and cancel all notifications in a background if app is killed by swiping. This caused some issues with service in Android O and above. I found out that you have to start your service differently, but this service start will crash my app with 
Error: `Reason: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()`

I dont have solution how to cancel all of my `Alarms` in a background yet, but this background service is very important for push notifications from server later in a project.(offtopic)

Initializing service in my `Application` class:

```
private fun initBackgroundService(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(Intent(this, AppService::class.java))
        } else {
            startService(Intent(this, AppService::class.java))
        }
    }
```

`AppService` class:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder

    class AppService: Service(){

        override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
            return null
        }


        override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
            return START_STICKY
        }

        override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
            super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
            val nManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            nManager.cancelAll()
            stopSelf()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your background task in a variable, and try to call `yourVariable.stop()` in the `onStop()` method of your Activity.

```
class YourClass() {
    var myService : Intent? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        myService = Intent(this, AppService::class.java)
        // do your stuff here
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        myService?.stop() // Or any 'cancel' or 'stop' method in your service
    }
}
```